# Macro preprocessor, multiple values

Tags: c, macros, microcontroller, c-preprocessor

I know that people usually define macro with a single value, such as:

```
#define PIN0 0x01
```

but what does it mean by this one with multiple values?

```
#define POWER_UP 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80
```

Supposedly, I need to send the packets 0x02, 0x01, 0x00.... sequentially. If not using this macro, I will probably use an array.  However, the toolchain generate this macro to me but I don't know how to use this to send the packets.  It doesn't look like the array definition of macro.  Does anyone know how I shall use this?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything special.  As usual, the right-hand side is substituted wherever the left-hand side appears.

Comment: Is there any way that i can extract the value one by one from the macro?  For example, if I want to print out 0x02 and 0x01 and 0x00... etc. seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you're asking about the packets (some more code would help) but:

```
char vals[] = { POWER_UP };
size_t i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(vals); ++i) {
    /* do something with vals[i] */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//test.c
#define POWER_UP 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80

POWER_UP
```

---

```
#only preprocessing
>gcc -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"


0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80
```

---

As you can see it will replace the macro will your list of values.

Answer (score 0):

It simply expands to `0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80` whenever the `POWER_UP` macro is referenced.